# «Знак отличия Военного ордена.» Верно написано?

Tags: прописная

И где найти правило написания с большой буквы, в данном случае слова *Военного*.

Comment: "Знак отличия Военного ордена".  Точка всегда ставится в конце или вообще не ставится (при наличии других знаков. Иногда ставится одновременно с другими знаками после кавычек.  Но никогда не ставится перед кавычками.. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163

Comment: да дело не в точке и не в кавычках...

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос, а просто замечание по оформлению вопроса. Точка всегда ставится в конце предложения, желательно, чтобы редакторы поправили. Но если что-нибудь неясно с ответом, пожалуйста, спрашивайте дополнительно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Зна́к отли́чия Вое́нного о́рдена**. Это старое название (до 1917 года). Слово *Военный* в данном случае входит в имя собственное, поэтому пишется с прописной буквы. В то же время может  существовать нарицательное сочетание, например военный орден Красной Звезды.

1) Немного истории

**Зна́к отли́чия Вое́нного о́рдена** — причисленная к **ордену Святого Георгия** награда в Русской императорской армии для нижних чинов с 1807 по 1917 годы. До 1913 года имел неофициальное название **Гео́ргиевский крест**; в 1913 году оно было официально закреплено в статуте.
16 декабря 1917 г. Георгиевский крест был упразднён одновременно со всеми остальными наградами Российской Республики.

Знак отличия «Георгиевский крест» был восстановлен в Российской Федерации в 1992 году: …восстановить российский **военный орден Святого Георгия и знак «Георгиевский Крест».**

**О́рден Свято́го Гео́ргия** — высшая военная награда Российской Федерации с 8 августа 2000 года. Орден Святого Георгия является высшей военной наградой Российской Федерации. Награждённые носят **знаки** всех степеней **ордена Святого Георгия.** Орден Святого Георгия I и II степени имеет знак и звезду, III и IV степени — только знак.

2) Пояснение

Орден и знак отличия меняли свое название. Также следует учитывать, что  родовые понятия орден и знак могут входить или не входить в имя собственное (в обоих случаях написание со строчной буквы). [§ 20. Названия орденов, медалей, знаков отличия, премий](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=24#pp24)

**Старое название**: Военный орден, или орден Святого Георгия; знак отличия Военного ордена, или Георгиевский крест.

**Современное название**: орден Святого Георгия; знак ордена Святого Георгия, или "Георгиевский Крест"

Answer (score 0):

[Импера́торский Вое́нный о́рден Свято́го Великому́ченика и Победоно́сца Гео́ргия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) - 
название ордена. В расширенном смысле — это всеохватывающий комплекс отличий офицеров, нижних чинов и воинских подразделений. А [зна́к отли́чия Вое́нного о́рдена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82) — одна из наград этого комплекса, учрежденная для нижних чинов.

Розенталь пишет: "В названиях орденов, не выделяемых кавычками (в большинстве случаев речь идет об отечественных наградах), все слова, кроме слов *орден* и *степень*, пишутся с прописной буквы". Так что не вызывает сомнения, что слово *Военного* пишется с прописной буквы. А вот почему слова  *знак отличия* пишутся со строчной буквы? Скорее всего, названием в полном смысле считалась  только "главная" часть, общая для ордена в целом.